# Multiple divs, same width, different height, floating left, how do I get them to go bottom of outer div and then grow upwards?

Tags: html

Okay, so for some personal usage and fun I've made a statistics chart that I build using HTML and PHP.

[Statistics chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BXRgH.png)

As you see, they float left, they go to bottom as intended with the downside all those divs are stacking on the height that the highest div reaches.

I've tried multiple things making them stack at bottom and grow upwards one by one, without success.

this is the raw source it outputs to the browser:

```
<div id="visitor_chart_outer">
        <div id="visitor_chart_inner">
            <div style="width: 9px; height: 30px;" class="visitor_chart_item visitor_chart_item_1"></div>
            <div style="width: 9px; height: 18px;" class="visitor_chart_item visitor_chart_item_2"></div>
            <div style="width: 9px; height: 22px;" class="visitor_chart_item visitor_chart_item_1"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    #visitor_chart_outer {
    width: 760px;
    height: 476px;
    background-color: #4e4e4e;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    margin: auto;
}

    #visitor_chart_inner {
    width: 750px;
    height: 466px;
    background-image:url(/images/status_chart/visitor_chart.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    padding-left: 26px;
}

    .visitor_chart_item_1 {
    background-color: #888888;
}

    .visitor_chart_item_2 {
    background-color: #afafaf;
}
```

Anyone have a clue how to overcome the divs special t

Comment: The `<center>` element is obsolete. Don't use that. https://developers.whatwg.org/obsolete.html#obsolete

Comment: I use that to make the entire statistics table stay in middle of the website :), but changed #visitor_chart_outer to have margin: auto;